# Editing data with fetch put method in redux, resulting in 404 (Not Found)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have to make `input` fields which can change existing data. I am doing it as I would do it in React, but it seems that im missing something here so my `React-Redux` app is throwing error:

```
EditUser.js:11 PUT http://localhost:3000/users/fe917ae4-4d9c-40ae-b160-ae8ef5b4f7a7 404 (Not Found)
```

Whole code:

```
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { useState } from "react";

const EditUser = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const history = useHistory();
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  function updateUser() {
    let item = { name, email };
    fetch(`http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(item),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    }).then(() => {
      history.replace("/");
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
        }}
      />{" "}
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={updateUser}>Update User</button>
    </div>
  );
};
export default EditUser;
```

If someone could help me I would be grateful, because i spent whole day trying find out how to edit simple data. In `React` i didnt had problems with it.

Comment: seems like it cannot find your url: `http://localhost:3000/users/${id}`. You can double check the `url` again. Or add `"proxy": "http://localhost:3000"` into your `package.json`